# Changing background image of Listbox Items

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, expression-blend

I want to toggle the background of my listbox items based on the selection status.

I initially hard-coded the background in my ItemTemplate like so:

```
   <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="PodImages\podstate-Clip.png" />
   </StackPanel.Background>
```

I attempted to go into Blend to set the background based on the visual states (selected vs not selected), but couldn't figure out Blend and I still don't understanding the styling markup. Can someone help me out with the style markup or guide me a bit in Blend on where I can set this?

edit: 
ok, I've found how I can add a list item to a list box and set the background based on a visual state in blend, but I can't figure out how to do this for the datatemplate items

edit:
Ok, I think what I want do do in a style would be something like this (but this crashes my app)

I modified

```
<Storyboard>
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ImageSource" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="PodImages/podstate-Clipped.png"/>
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

here is the style in total:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle2" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ImageSource" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="PodImages/podstate-Clip.png"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ImageSource" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="PodImages/podstate-Clipped.png"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <ContentControl.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" x:Name="ContentBackground" ImageSource="PodImages/podstate-Clip.png"/>
                            </ContentControl.Background>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: going with a button for now. Hopefully someone knows a good way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the {Binding ResourceName} in your Listbox background, have a look here for some more tips http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/silverlight-data-binding

alternatively I suggest you search for "Databinding in Silverlight" that will give you tons of information